# How can I access the DOM of a <webview> in Electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, electron

I'm just getting started with Electron, with prior experience with node-webkit (nw.js).

In nw.js, I was able to create iframes and then access the DOM of said iframe in order to grab things like the title, favicon, &c. When I picked up Electron a few days ago to port my nw.js app to it, I saw advice to use webviews instead of iframes, simply because they were better. Now, the functionality I mentioned above was relatively easy to do in nw.js, but I don't know how to do it in Electron (and examples are slim to none). Can anyone help?

Also, I have back/forward buttons for my webview (and I intend on having more than one). I saw in the documentation that I could call functions for doing so on a webview, but nothing I have tried worked either (and, I haven't found examples of them being used in the wild).

Comment: For future searchers: best bet is to use the ipc module. There's a nice simple example of how you can use this to communicate between your main page and your webview in the electron docs: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#event-ipc-message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides guest to host IPC calls as [NetOperatorWibby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167646/netoperator-wibby), it is also very useful to go from host to guest. The only way to do this at present is to use the [<webview>.executeJavaScript(code, userGesture)](http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/api/web-view-tag/#lt-webview-gt-executejavascript-code-usergesture). This api is a bit crude but it works.

If you are working with a remote guest, like "extending" a third party web page, you can also utilize webview [preload](http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/api/web-view-tag/#preload)  attribute which executes your custom script before any other scripts are run on the page. Just note that the preload api, for security reasons, will nuke any functions that are created in the root namespace of your custom JS file when your custom script finishes, however this custodial process will not nuke any objects you declare in the root. So if you want your custom functions to persist, bundle them into a singleton object and your custom APIs will persist after the page fully loads.

[update] Here is a simple example that I just finished writing: [Electron-Webview-Host-to-Guest-RPC-Sample](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/Electron-Webview-Host-to-Guest-RPC-Sample)

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to try that. Do you have any examples of that executeJavaScript function?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll scratch up a basic example.

Comment: The example I posted is very basic but you should get the gist of the idea. I just came across this last night so I'm just starting but I forsee that I will write a single handler in the guest that accepts a Base64 encoded JSON message which would be decoded and processed in the guest handler.

Comment: Oh wow, I just tried out your example and it's awesome! You're really good at JavaScript dude! Haha!

Comment: LOL. Thanks =^) We are in exiting days with tools like Node and Electron. This was the stuff of dreams when I started doing heavy JS coding back in the 2003.

Comment: Hey @JavaScriptDude , Your answer seems good. But I want to integrate external site which has its own heavy minified JS which assumes that it will be integrated within <iFrame> and communicates to main site every second. I dont even know how many times and from where it fires events which will be listened in main site. In that case can I use <webview> instead if <iframe>? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hey @kamal, I have not used <iframe> to solve this problem so it may be best to refactor your question into a new SO post. Cheers - JSD

Answer (score 12):

I dunno who voted to close my question, but I'm glad it didn't go through. Other people have this question elsewhere online too. I also explained what I wanted to achieve, but w/e.

---

I ended up using `ipc-message`. The [documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/api/web-view-tag/#event-39-ipc-message-39) could use more examples/explanations for the layperson, but hey, I figured it out. My code is [here](https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries/blob/master/resources/scripts/aries.js) and [here](https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries/blob/master/resources/scripts/browser.js), but I will also post examples below should my code disappear for whatever reason.

---

This code is in `aries.js`, and this file is included in the main renderer page, which is `index.html`.

```
var ipc = require("ipc");
var webview = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs-pane active")[0];

webview.addEventListener("ipc-message", function (e) {
  if (e.channel === "window-data") {
    // console.log(e.args[0]);

    $(".tab.active .tab-favicon").attr("src", e.args[0].favicon);
    $(".tab.active .tab-title").html(e.args[0].title);
    $("#url-bar").val(e.args[0].url);

    $("#aries-titlebar h1").html("Aries | " + e.args[0].title);
  }

  // TODO
  // Make this better...cancel out setTimeout?
  var timer;

  if (e.channel === "mouseover-href") {
    // console.log(e.args[0]);
    $(".linker").html(e.args[0]).stop().addClass("active");

    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      $(".linker").stop().removeClass("active");
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```

---

This next bit of code is in `browser.js`, and this file gets injected into my `<webview>`.

```
var ipc = require("ipc");

document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
  var hoveredEl = e.target;

  if (hoveredEl.tagName !== "A") {
    return;
  }

  ipc.sendToHost("mouseover-href", hoveredEl.href);
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var data = {
    "title": document.title,
    "url": window.location.href,
    // need to make my own version, can't rely on Google forever
    // maybe have this URL fetcher hosted on hikar.io?
    "favicon": "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" + window.location.href
  };

  ipc.sendToHost("window-data", data);
});
```

---

I haven't found a reliable way to inject jQuery into `<webview>`s, and I probably shouldn't because the page I would be injecting might already have it (in case you're wondering why my main code is jQuery, but there's also regular JavaScript).

Comment: What do you mean by "this file gets injected into my <webview>". Do you include the file in the guest - website or is the injection done by some electron code?

Comment: The webview is a div. Like <section>. Electron allows me to put browser.js into the webview that's loading a website.

Comment: Do you put it in by using preload attribute? (<webview src="https://www.github.com/" preload="./test.js"></webview>)

Comment: Yup https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/Aries/blob/master/resources/scripts/aries.js#L86-L90

Comment: If I follow your example correctly I get `module.js:440 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'ipc'` from my `render.js` file, which is "included" from my main `html` page via the `<script>` tag. Is this what you mean by "included" or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @hippietrail use `require("electron").ipcRenderer` instead

Answer (score 0):

This relates to previous answer (I am not allowed to comment): Important info regarding `ipc` module for users of Electron 1.x:

The ipc module was split into two separate modules:

- **ipcMain** for the main process
- **ipcRenderer** for the renderer process

So, the above examples need to be corrected, instead of

```
// Outdated - doesn't work in 1.x    
var ipc = require("ipc");
```

use:

```
// In main process.
var ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain
```

And:

```
// In renderer process.
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer
```

See: http://electron.atom.io/blog/2015/11/17/electron-api-changes section on 'Splitting the ipc module'