# Accessing the DOM from webview in atom Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, electron, atom-editor

Is it possible to scrape html from the webview element in the atom electron desktop development toolkit, I am trying to access the DOM but i get nothing back, i have tried a document.links in the console at runtime but i get empty properties and objects in return?

```
 window.onresize = doLayout;
 var isLoading = false;

onload = function() {
var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
doLayout();

var t = webview.executeJavaScript("console.log(document.links);");

document.querySelector('#back').onclick = function() {
webview.goBack();
};

<object is="browserplugin" type="application/browser-plugin" id="browser-plugin-1" style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></object>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: the value of t is displayed as undefined in the debugger

Comment: maybe it's a duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523171/how-can-i-access-the-dom-of-a-webview-in-electron

Comment: so i should be trying either an iframe which is injected into the webview or an ipc request? right?

Comment: I posted some markup which shows what is actually inside the webview tag, now there is a way of extracting html from the object but it is of type browser plugin, can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: the markup is in the browser.html and js code is in the browser.js file respectively

Answer (score 7):

Your `console.log` is logging to the webview's console, not your parent renderer process' console. Run `document.querySelector('webview').openDevTools()` from your parent renderer (after you have a `src` on the webview, it's additional methods aren't available until then). This will open another dev tools window. From that console, you should see your log. Note that webviews and the renderer hosting the webview are two separate `webContents` instances and two separate renderer processes. You can communicate between them or the main process via IPC.

Not sure what your goals are, but if you want to do DOM manipulation in a webview, I'd recommend using a [preload script](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-view-tag/#preload). This script gets run before the webview's JS and gives you access to all node.js and renderer electron APIs as well as the DOM. `executeJavaScript` is going to be a long difficult road, whereas `preload` scripts were built for this kind of use case.

Here's an example demonstrating 1) opening the devtools of a webview, 2) running a preload script in the webview's context that access the DOM, 3) communicating between the parent renderer process and it's child webview process via IPC: https://github.com/ccnokes/electron-tutorials/tree/master/preload-scripts

Comment: ok as im very new to electron, could i please have an example or sample project showing scraping from a webview?

Comment: @apaul yeah I'll throw together an example soon and post it here

Comment: @apaul added the example

Comment: thanks alot, i have been reading the code and it will help me during the development of my own browser

Comment: Great! If it helped, be sure to accept my answer :)