# How can I access the contents of a <webview> (Electron/NW.JS)?

Tags: webview, electron, nwjs

I was using the `<webview>` tag instead of iFrames, but couldn't find much details on the [NWJS docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/webview%20Tag/), the [Electron docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag), nor on the actual [`<webview>` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) around accessing the content inside of it.

I wanted to retrieve the `document.title` from within the `<webview>`, and send that back to the main process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic solution I went with for communicating between a main process and inside of a `<webview>`, is to use Webview's [`ContentWindow.postMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-ContentWindow) method. This is very similar to [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). By using `postMessage()`—specifically tracking the `event.source`—we create a communication bridge between the main process and the `<webview>`.

```js
const webview = document.getElementById('your-webview-element');

// <webview> Content is loaded
function contentload() {
  // The following will be injected in the webview
  const webviewInjectScript = `
      var data = {
        title: document.title,
        url: window.location.href
      };

      function respond(event) {
        event.source.postMessage(data, '*');
      }

      window.addEventListener("message", respond, false);
  `;

  webview.executeScript({
    code: webviewInjectScript
  });
}

// <webview> Loading has finished
function loadstop() {
  webview.contentWindow.postMessage("Send me your data!", "*"); // Send a request to the webview
}

// Bind events
webview.addEventListener("contentload", contentload);
webview.addEventListener("loadstop", loadstop);
window.addEventListener("message", receiveHandshake, false); // Listen for response

function receiveHandshake(event) {
  // Data is accessible as event.data.*
  // This is the custom object that was injected during contentload()
  // i.e. event.data.title, event.data.url
  console.log(event.data)

  // Unbind EventListeners
  removeListeners();
}

// Remove all event listeners
function removeListeners() {
  webview.removeEventListener("contentload", contentload);
  webview.removeEventListener("loadstop", loadstop);
  window.removeEventListener("message", receiveHandshake);
}
```

How it works (at least one way I've found):

1. Firstly, bind EventListeners from the main process to the `<webview>` and the window (to listen later on for a message coming from within the `<webview>`)
2. When the `<webview>` element loads a URL, it triggers `contentload()`
3. `contentload()` will inject an EventListener into the `<webview>` and setup the data/DOM elements we want to get from inside of the `<webview>`.
4. Once the `<webview>` finishes loading, it triggers `loadstop()`
5. `loadstop()` will send a message to the `<webview>` to establish a bridge. It's important to note that here I use `webview.contentWindow.postMessage()` instead of `window.postMessage()`.
6. The `<webview>` responds with the data we setup on step 1
7. When the main process receives the response back (via EventListener "message") from the `<webview>`, it triggers `receiveHandshake()`
8. Inside of `receiveHandshake()` you now have access the data that came from inside of the `<webview>`. This can be the page title—or whatever you configured in the `webviewInjectScript`.
9. Finally, I call `removeListeners()` to remove all the EventListeners we setup, but you could keep sending messages back-and-forth.

---

FYI—in the context of Electron and NWJS, the `<webview>` tag allows you to render websites (like an iframe), with the benefit that it runs in a separate process. This is much better for performance than a bunch of iframes. A `<webview>` contains a standard HTML document, the complication over say an iframe is because it runs in a separate process.

There's also [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523171/how-can-i-access-the-dom-of-a-webview-in-electron) with some other solutions, such as using IPC messages, and using the `preload` tag.

---

### UPDATED: Using a front-end framework (i.e. Vue)

There's another way to do this that's more proper for Electron. In the code below, I'm using Vue (2) and Webpack, but the key differences from the above implementation are:

- Use the Electron `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` to send messages, instead of `postMessage`
- Load the injection script using the `preload` property of Webview, instead of using `executeScript()`. I've binded the `:preload` value to the Vue computed property (`injectScript`), which returns the path of the external `injectWebPageScript.js` file.

components/myComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <webview ref="frame" class="frame" :preload="injectScript"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    injectScript() {
      const appPath = require("electron").remote.app.getAppPath();
      return `file://${require("path").resolve(
        __dirname,
        "../../mixins/injectWebPageScript.js"
      )}`;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mySiteLoaderScript(url) {
      const frame = this.$refs.frame;

      // Initialize event listeners on the Webview
      addListeners();

      // Set the URL, start loading
      frame.setAttribute("src", url);

      // Bind events
      function addListeners() {
        frame.addEventListener("dom-ready", contentloaded);
        frame.addEventListener("ipc-message", receiveHandshake);
      }

      // Remove all event listeners
      function removeListeners() {
        frame.removeEventListener("dom-ready", contentloaded);
        frame.removeEventListener("ipc-message", receiveHandshake);
      }

      // Once webview content is loaded, request its data
      function contentloaded() {
        frame.send("requestData");
      }

      // Triggered when we receive a response from the Webview
      // This is the `ipc-message` event
      function receiveHandshake(event) {
        // Only listen to replyData messages
        if (event.channel !== "replyData") return false;

        const data = event.args[0];
        const title = data.title;
        const favicon = data.favicon;

        // Remove listeners once data has been received
        removeListeners();
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.mySiteLoaderScript("https://stackoverflow.com");
  }
};
</script>
```

mixins/injectWebPageScript.js

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

// Once the Webview's document has been loaded, notify the ipcRenderer
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  ipcRenderer.on("requestData", () => {
    ipcRenderer.sendToHost("replyData", {
      title: document.title,
      url: window.location.href
    });
  });
});
```